# Get event for closing browser and event for navigating action

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have been develop one solution to do something in the backend using the `onBeforeUnload` and `onUnload`, I already handled successfully the back end call but I need to separate the events when the browser is closed and when the user just click in another link to navigate to some page else, I need something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            if(isClose)
                doSomething...
            else if(navigating_to_otherPage)
                doSomethingElse...
        .....
```

Comment: You can't. To the browser, they are one and the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott mentioned, you can't really.

The exception to this would be if your "page" was actually part of a single-page app (like a SPA Angular, React or Vue app).

With applications like this, you simulate multiple pages by just changing what is shown. This way, the `onBeforeUnload()` would only be for closing the browser or navigating away from the SPA, and then your SPA code can detect page change.

Not completely fool-proof, but it'd generally be acceptable for most use-cases if you absolutely need it.